# on_raw_reaction_add - client.get_user(payload.user_id) returns None

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make the bot that adds the role if people react to a reaction, **it worked perfectly before, and all of a sudden it stops working**

client.get_user(payload.user_id) this was supposed to return the user but it returns None instead, I printed user_id and it worked, printing my own ID, but as I add the get_user it returns None instantly (I am using my own ID)

I dont know what happened, I made sure discor.py was at the latest update

here is the relevant code part: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/olivohevud.cs

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With discord.py 1.5.x setting up intents is necessary for your events to work properly.

1. Go to your discord developer portal.
2. Click your application.
3. Click your bot.
4. Scroll down to "Privileged Gateway Intents" and turn on both.

Add this to your code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()

# If you are using client
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# If you are using bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```